# Python program runs without erros but doesn't give desired output

Tags: python, for-loop

Tried to generate multiple files from already existing ones, changing a couple of lines from the existing files using this program but didn't get any new files. Can anyone please help and suggest changes?

```
    import os
    sourcedir = "/home/abc/xyz/mdp/"
    destdir = "/home/abc/xyz/mdb/"
    for filename in os.listdir(sourcedir):
      if not filename.endswith(".mdp"):
         continue
      source = os.path.join(sourcedir, filename)
      dest = os.path.join(destdir, filename)     
      fin = open('/home/abc/xyz/mdp/md_1.mdp')
      fout = open('/home/abc/xyz/mdb/md_1.mdp', "w")
      lines = fin.readlines()

      for line in lines:
        line = line.replace('integrator               = md', 'integrator               = md- 
             vv')
        line = line.replace('dt                       = 0.001', 'dt                       = 
            -0.001')
        fout.write(line)
      fin.close()
      fout.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried throwing in some `print` statements around the important operations, e.g. each time a file is opened, closed, skipped, etc?

Comment: Be more specific. What output *do* you get and what is the desired output?

Comment: @Junuxx the desired output is multiple files which are like the original files except for a couple of lines that I'm changing.

Comment: I have md_1.mdp, md_2.mdp and so on upto 1000, I want to change a couple of lines in each of these and generate one file from each of these 1000 as new files without losing the original ones.

Comment: Have you tried closing `fin`after reading the lines, and then opening `fout`? I'm not sure you can read from and write to the same file simultaneously.

Comment: in line 9 yue should write fin = open(source) and in line 10 you should write fout = open(dest, "w"). Now you read several times the same file: '/home/abc/xyz/mdp/md_1.mdp'.

Comment: @Junuxx the names are different, last directory names are different (mdp <.> mdb).

Comment: You should use context managers to handle file objects, they're great.

Comment: Thanks @Zoltan, it now works. Thank you so much. I thank everyone for their help. Hope all your wishes come true.